# How can I load two Eclipse projects with conflicting names in two different working sets?

Tags: eclipse, conflict, working-set

I have two Eclipse working sets (WorkingSet 0.1.x and WorkingSet 0.2.x). I need to do work on them interchangeably, though neither interacts with the other. The problem is that some of the projects obviously have the same name (MyProject, MyModule). Even if I close all of the projects in WorkingSet 0.1.x, I can't even add the 0.2.x version of that project to WorkingSet 0.2.x because there is already an instance of it in the workspace. Aside from renaming my projects or deleting everything out of the workspace each time I need to switch to a different branch, how can I use working sets to keep these independent? Or do I need two separate **workspaces**, which seems like overkill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot rename the project - the only option you have is to use different workspaces, which is not a terrible idea, since you mentioned that projects don't interact with each other.

Comment: I understand -- it's just that all of the settings, etc. are tied to the workspace, so duplicating the workspace and then keeping any changes in sync is an additional hassle which I felt the working sets should have handled.

Comment: IMO its much easier to rename the projects then.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found a viable solution for this. I create multiple working sets representing branches and create relevant projects as mentioned here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=102121

Again, you will need to have a unique name for your project in the workspace but this does the job for me.